# How to configure error/warnings for (not) using dot notation property access?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm curious if it's possible to enable warnings related to dot notation property access? In my scenario, I'd like to enforce a "style" of using dot notation when a @property has been exposed to consumer.

I took a quick peak through the options related to static analysis in "Build Settings" but nothing jumped out at me.

Note: I know under the hood it's all messages, but for static analysis it seems like this is something that might exist.

Comment: I don't believe there is any such warning specifically because there are so many occurrences of things like `someArray.count` in a typical codebase.  We argued long and hard about this particular design decision when we designed `@property` and the dot syntax.   We landed on basically treating the dot syntax as synonymous with method invocation save for also requiring a non-generic target (i.e. not id).

Comment: Fair enough! I just found myself working on an "ancient" and inconsistently styled objc project and wanted assistance in normalizing the thing. Do you have any tips/tools for further linting/static analysis?

Comment: Not really;  you might be able to click on the declaration of the method or property and look for all callers?   I believe that is in the context menu in the Xcode editor?